# Excel lookup formula on another sheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 2 worksheets. I want to be able to calculate the nominal length based on the shape code which have different formulas for different shape codes. Parameters are in nominal length. Please see pictures to get a clearer picture.

Nominal length:

[image: Nominal length]

Formula:

[image: Formula]

Comment: Do you only have these 4 combinations A, A+B, A+B+C & A+B+C+D or there could be more because I see columns upto G? If you have only these 4 combinations a possible but somewhat inconvenient   IF can be used to map text formula to actual formula. Can the conditions change in future e.g. can it become B-C or A+B-D something like that,  combinations of basic math operator? Is your requirement something like if I enter say 14 in col T then since 14 maps to A+C cols E & G should add up and show the actual result in G? This could be possible using VBA macros, not too sure if formula may work easily.

Comment: It can be all the way up to G. These formulas is just a part of it. I have around 80 formulas and may be added when need be. It is always an addition, just using which parameters A to G.

Comment: Yes, but do you need the formula result in column O? You have shown 'nominal length' in your above picture e.g. if I enter say 11 in T3, since 11 maps to A+B in lookup table it should add respective E3 & F3 columns and show you the addition in O3. Is this how it should work. I can think of some VBA code that does so. Is the lookup table in a separate xls file or within the same xls workbook but a different worksheet e.g. Sheet1 is your data and Sheet2 is your lookup table in same filename.xls for example.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your question, I am suggesting a following VBA based solution.

Assumption – Sheet1 has the data table in excel columns A thru T. Table column names A thru G map to actual excel columns E thru K. Sheet2 has the ShapeCode Lookup Table in cell range D4 thru E12. The Calculation options are set to Automatic which is the default setting in Excel.

[image]
In Sheet1 press ALT + F11. VBA Code editor shall open. From Insert Menu Insert a Module. Module named Module1 (Assuming there are no other modules present) shall get inserted and the name shall appear in the left pane. Mostly it shall also open the code editor window for Module1, if not, double click on Module1 to open the VBA Code editor. Here past the below code.

```
Function EvaluateExp(parm1 As String, parm2 As Long, parm3 As Long)

    ' parm1 is the VLOOKUP String
    ' parm2 is the row number
    ' parm3 is the column number of the first column in the table A thru G

    Application.Volatile
    Dim finalstring As String
    finalstring = ""

    For I = 1 To Len(parm1)
          If I Mod 2 = 0 Then          ' it's even position

                Select Case Mid(parm1, I, 1)

                ' Ensure only + opertor is allowed. In future add more Case statements
                ' below in case more math operators are applicable

                    Case "+"
                          finalstring = finalstring & Mid(parm1, I, 1)
                    Case Else
                          EvaluateExp = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                          Exit Function
                End Select

          Else                         ' it's odd position
              J = UCase(Mid(parm1, I, 1))

              ' Construct the expression from the actual columns mapping to A thru G
              ' In future if you insert more columns after G, add new Case statements here below

              Select Case J
                 Case "A"
                     finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3).Address
                 Case "B"
                     finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 1).Address
                 Case "C"
                     finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 2).Address
                 Case "D"
                     finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 3).Address
                 Case "E"
                     finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 4).Address
                 Case "F"
                     finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 5).Address
                 Case "G"
                     finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 6).Address
                 Case Else
                     EvaluateExp = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                     Exit Function
              End Select

           End If

     Next I

   EvaluateExp = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Evaluate(finalstring)

End Function
```

This code create a custom function named EvaluateExp that takes in 3 parameters. Input string, Row number & Column number. This function maps the Table Columns A thru G to Excel Columns E Thru K respectively and constructs the expected Excel expression, wrapped in Evaluate returns the actual result.

In Sheet1 in cell O3 enter the following formula built around this custom function  and then drag it down along the required rows of the table.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(T3),"",EvaluateExp(VLOOKUP(T3,Sheet2!$D$4:$E$12,2,FALSE),ROW(),COLUMN(E3)))
```

As you enter Shape Code in cell T3 and below, the formula returns the expected sum of applicable columns as per the expression returned by lookup.

The formula shall return #VALUE! in following situations

•   Lookup value does not exist in lookup table

•   Referring to columns other than A thru G in the expression

•   Incomplete/Invalid expression in lookup table e.g. A+B+ or ABCD or A+BC

•   Expression containing math operator other than + e.g. A-C

Limitations

•   The function maps Table Columns A thru G to actual Excel columns E thru K.
 In future if you insert more columns after G you need to update the code to accommodate the same.

[image]

---

### Update

The following code for User Defined Function is generic enough to support any valid mathematical expression. If the expression can not be evaluated it shall return #VALUE! error. If brackets are omitted it should follow the operator precedence as documented [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-Excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a). Mention all applicable operators in the expression e.g. (2*A)+(3*B) and not 2A+3B.

```
Function EvaluateExp(parm1 As String, parm2 As Long, parm3 As Long)

    ' parm1 is the VLOOKUP String
    ' parm2 is the row number
    ' parm3 is the column number of the first column in the table A thru G

    Application.Volatile
    Dim finalstring As String
    finalstring = ""

    For I = 1 To Len(parm1)
        J = UCase(Mid(parm1, I, 1))
        Select Case J
             Case "A"
                  finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3).Address
             Case "B"
                  finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 1).Address
             Case "C"
                  finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 2).Address
             Case "D"
                  finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 3).Address
             Case "E"
                  finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 4).Address
             Case "F"
                  finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 5).Address
             Case "G"
                  finalstring = finalstring & Cells(parm2, parm3 + 6).Address
             Case Else
                  finalstring = finalstring & J

        End Select

    Next I


   EvaluateExp = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Evaluate(finalstring)

End Function
```

Comment: Great. Got it to work. Million thanks. How do i add extra math operators instead of just "+" i.e "*" and "-". Thanks

Comment: See my inline comments in the code. There's a Case Statement therein, Select Case Mid(parm1, I, 1). The first evaluation is for Case "+" just add more Case statements below it matching the operator. e.g. Case "-" and the following statement  finalstring = finalstring & Mid(parm1, I, 1)  below it.

Comment: Ok. If let's say the formula is 2A + 0.5B. Do i put the formula as (2*A) + (0.5*B). I have put the case statement for "*" but it doesn't seem to accept the number 2 or any other numbers.

Comment: See updated answer above.Incorporate the same and revert back in case of any issues.